# REGEX capture each n-letters words between two words of a sentence

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm having a hard time trying to select only n-length words between two words of a sentence :
ex:
for the statement :
"this is the start some words are to be selected end no more select"

Let's say I'd like to select 3+ words between the word 'start' and 'end', the result would capture
some, words, are selected ignoring to and be.

https://regex101.com/r/Ost7Wn/3

Just selecting [\w]{3,} is working by itself but I can't figure out how to put it between the words 'start' and 'end' in the sentence to match my n-letter words that appears only between them.  I've tried many things, from lookaround to capture groups, but I really can't get it!

Any ideas ?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex with a lookahead and `\G`:

```
(?:\bSTART\b|(?!^)\G)\h+(?!END\b).*?\b(\w{3,})(?=.*?\bEND\b)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ost7Wn/13)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?:\bSTART\b|(?!^)\G)`: Match word `START` or starting from end of previous match match 0 or more words separated by 1+ whitespace.
- `\G`: asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match
- `\h+(?!END\b).*?(\w{4,})`: Match 1+ whitespace followed 0 or more characters followed by a word of 4+ length which is captured in group #1
- `(?=.*?\bEND\b)`: Lookahead to assert presence of word `END` ahead

Comment: yes it does, thanks for your contribution.  never heard of \G before,  Regex are fascinating!

Comment: btw, i found something in your regex :(  if you put a non 4 letter right next to the start, it doesnot match anymore ...

Comment: cool, it works perfectly now.  could you please explain to me the difference ?

Comment: what if 'start' and 'end' could be interchaneable but must appears both (i mean start .... start is not accepted but end .... start would )

Comment: @anubhava This fails if you were to have multiple `END` anchors for example `START one two three END one two END` would match `one, two, END, one, two`

Comment: @anubhava It also breaks the moment your text string has punctuation

Comment: Problem is all about words, punctuation is not part of question but this regex can easily be modified if requirements change in future.

Comment: suppose start and end could switch positions (could begin with end and vice versa) as condition would be START|END on both sides how can I assert that at least one START and one END is present in the sentence ?

Comment: i mean something like this : https://regex101.com/r/Ost7Wn/15 actually it does capture only the first n-letter word instead of all the sequence ....

Comment: This is how it will match with my posted regex: https://regex101.com/r/Ost7Wn/17 Are you trying to solve a different problem?

Comment: no, i am learning how regex engine is working, and I wonder how to go further with the same problem.  I've simplified the expression and tests phrases to let know understand my question : suppose we want all 'c' between 'a' and 'b' or 'b' and 'a', it takes my first c and then ends, can you please explain why ? https://regex101.com/r/Ost7Wn/18

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223996/discussion-between-carl-verret-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 1):

If a quantifier in the lookbehind is supported, you might also use

```
(?<=\bSTART\s+(?:\w+\s+)*?)\w{3,}(?=(?:\s+\w+)*?\s+END\b)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert what is on the left is

  - `\bSTART\s+(?:\w+\s+)*?` Match *START* optionally repeated by word and whitespace chars
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `\w{3,}` Match 3 or more word chars
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what on the right is

  - `(?:\s+\w+)*?\s+END\b` Optionally repeat whitespace and word chars and match *END*
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rQizQk/1)

Comment: wow, thank you so much, ater hours and hours, I can finally understand my mistake! I wasn't adding optionnal 'non greedy' search for words in my look behind and neither in my lookahead! This is SO clear now, cant thank you enough!

Comment: too bad quantified lookbehind is not supported in java ? :(

Comment: @Carl Verret It is, but you have to specify a finite quantifier instead of an infinite quantifier. You could try `(?<=\bSTART\s{1,10}(?:\w+\s{1,10}){0,1000})\w{3,}(?=(?:\s+\w+)*?\s+END\b)` https://regex101.com/r/MfNElT/1

Comment: you're right!  but the {0,1000} goes on the other side of the

Comment: Try making it no greedy `{0,1000}?`

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting scenario. Typically you would do better to extract the string `start(.*)end` from the main source and then run your RegEx on the substring.

That doesn't mean it isn't possible to do with one RegEx though!

I'm sure you've struggled with `positive|negative` `lookahead|lookbehind` and found that it's a real nuisance you can't do a dynamic length lookbehind e.g. `(?<=start.*)` as you can with `lookahead`.

For this example the key thing you have to understand is that RegEx moves the `cursor` position through the string as it matches... This is the caveat we will use to make this work.

**RegEx**

```
(?:.*start|^.*|end.*)|\b(\w{3,})(?=.*end)
(?:                                         : Start of non-capture group
   .*start                                  : [Match pattern 1a] matches anything upto and including the {start} anchor
          |                                 : OR operator
           ^.*                              : [Match pattern 1b] matches from the {^} start of the string to the end
              |                             : OR operator
               end.*                        : [Match pattern 1c] matches from the {end} anchor to the end of the string
                    )                       : End of non-capture group
                     |                      : OR operator
                      \b(\w{3,})(?=.*end)   : Captures a boundary [\b] followed by word characters [a-zA-Z0-9_] 3 or more times whilst using a positive lookahead to check that the {end} anchor hasn't been passed
```

**Wordy Explanation**

The above RegEx can be written, in simple terms:

```
    NON-CAPTURING_GROUP OR CAPTURING_GROUP
OR, more verbose
    (MATCH_PATTERN_1a OR MATCH_PATTERN_1b OR MATCH_PATTERN_1c) OR MATCH_PATTERN_2
```

- The `NON-CAPTURING_GROUP` is always evaluated first so we check here that we actually want to get matches

  - `MATCH_PATTERN_1a` checks that the `start` anchor is present and moves the `cursor` past that point in the string
  - `MATCH_PATTERN_1b` only matches if `1a` failed and the `start` anchor is present in the string. If so it matches everything and the expression stops.
  - `MATCH_PATTERN_1c` checks that the `end` anchor point hasn't been reached. If it has then it matches to the end of the string and the expression stops.
- The `CAPTURING_GROUP` is always evaluated second; so only matches *if it should*

  - `MATCH_PATTERN_2` matches any word boundary followed by word characters `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` between the lengths specified

    - It also checks with a `positive lookahead` to make sure the `end` anchor hasn't been passed

**Warning**

Be aware that the first and last capture will always be from the `NON-CAPTURE` group and should be ignored. Depending on how the regex is implemented it may be empty, the full match string, or both (multi-dimensional array).

**Example [Python]**

Note: `Python` outputs in the format `$result = $full_matches[]`
Note: `flag = re.I` has been set to make the RegEx case insensitive i.e. it matches `START` and `start`

```
import re

test_str1 = """one two three four START four five two five six END seven"""
test_str2 = """this is the start some words are to be selected end no more select"""
test_str3 = """these are some words that shouldn't be selected end also not selected"""
test_str4 = """end two four five two five six END seven"""
test_str5 = """one start two three end four five six end seven one"""
test_str6 = """END START two four five two five six seven"""

regex1 = r"(?:.*start|^.*|end.*)|\b(\w{3,})(?=.*end)"
regex2 = r"(?:.*start|^.*|end.*)|\b(\w{4,})(?=.*end)"

print(re.findall(regex1, test_str1, re.I))
print(re.findall(regex1, test_str2, re.I))
print(re.findall(regex1, test_str3, re.I))
print(re.findall(regex1, test_str4, re.I))
print(re.findall(regex1, test_str5, re.I))
print(re.findall(regex1, test_str6, re.I))

print(re.findall(regex2, test_str1, re.I))      
print(re.findall(regex2, test_str2, re.I))
print(re.findall(regex2, test_str3, re.I))
print(re.findall(regex2, test_str4, re.I))
print(re.findall(regex2, test_str5, re.I))
print(re.findall(regex2, test_str6, re.I))

'''
  Output:
    ['', 'four', 'five', 'two', 'five', 'six', '']
    ['', 'some', 'words', 'are', 'selected', '']
    ['']
    ['']
    ['', 'two', 'three', '']
    ['']
    ['', 'four', 'five', 'five', '']
    ['', 'some', 'words', 'selected', '']
    ['']
    ['']
    ['', 'three', '']
    ['']
'''
```

**Example [PHP]**

Note: `PHP` outputs in the format `$result = [$full_matches[], $capture_group[]]`
Note: `flag = i` has been set to make the RegEx case insensitive i.e. it matches `START` and `start`

```
$test_str1 = "one two three four START four five two five six END seven";
$test_str2 = "this is the start some words are to be selected end no more select";
$test_str3 = "these are some words that shouldn't be selected end also not selected";
$test_str4 = "end two four five two five six END seven";
$test_str5 = "one start two three end four five six end seven one";
$test_str6 = "END START two four five two five six seven";

$regex1 = "/(?:.*start|^.*|end.*)|\b(\w{3,})(?=.*end)/i";
$regex2 = "/(?:.*start|^.*|end.*)|\b(\w{4,})(?=.*end)/i";

preg_match_all($regex1, $test_str1, $matches1);
preg_match_all($regex1, $test_str2, $matches2);
preg_match_all($regex1, $test_str3, $matches3);
preg_match_all($regex1, $test_str4, $matches4);
preg_match_all($regex1, $test_str5, $matches5);
preg_match_all($regex1, $test_str6, $matches6);

preg_match_all($regex2, $test_str1, $matches7);
preg_match_all($regex2, $test_str2, $matches8);
preg_match_all($regex2, $test_str3, $matches9);
preg_match_all($regex2, $test_str4, $matches10);
preg_match_all($regex2, $test_str5, $matches11);
preg_match_all($regex2, $test_str6, $matches12);

echo json_encode($matches1);
echo "\n";
echo json_encode($matches2);
echo "\n";
echo json_encode($matches3);
echo "\n";
echo json_encode($matches4);
echo "\n";
echo json_encode($matches5);
echo "\n";
echo json_encode($matches6);
echo "\n";
echo json_encode($matches7);
echo "\n";
echo json_encode($matches8);
echo "\n";
echo json_encode($matches9);
echo "\n";
echo json_encode($matches10);
echo "\n";
echo json_encode($matches11);
echo "\n";
echo json_encode($matches12);

/*
  Output:
    [["one two three four START","four","five","two","five","six","END seven"],["","four","five","two","five","six",""]]
    [["this is the start","some","words","are","selected","end no more select"],["","some","words","are","selected",""]]
    [["these are some words that shouldn't be selected end also not selected"],[""]]
    [["end two four five two five six END seven"],[""]]
    [["one start","two","three","end four five six end seven one"],["","two","three",""]]
    [["END START"],[""]]
    [["one two three four START","four","five","five","END seven"],["","four","five","five",""]]
    [["this is the start","some","words","selected","end no more select"],["","some","words","selected",""]]
    [["these are some words that shouldn't be selected end also not selected"],[""]]
    [["end two four five two five six END seven"],[""]]
    [["one start","three","end four five six end seven one"],["","three",""]]
    [["END START"],[""]]
*/
```

#### .NET

If you were using `.NET` then the RegEx becomes far simpler:

```
start(\s*(?!end)\w+\s*)*end
```

That's because `.NET` allows you to capture all occurrences of a recused string.

#### Other methods

In reality it looks like you would do better to split the string down into substrings and evaluate from there...

**Input**

```
start one two three end start one two three end one two end
```

**Split Strings**

```
start(.*?)end

[0] => start one two three end
[1] => start one two three end one two end
```

**Match words**

```
\b\w{3,}
```

**Example**

```
$string = "start one two three end start four five six end one two end";

preg_match_all('/start(.*?)end/i', $string, $matches);

foreach($matches[1] as $match){
  preg_match_all('/\b\w{3,}/', $match, $out);
  var_dump($out);
}

/*
  Output:
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=>
        string(3) "one"
        [1]=>
        string(3) "two"
        [2]=>
        string(5) "three"
      }
    }
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=>
        string(4) "four"
        [1]=>
        string(4) "five"
        [2]=>
        string(3) "six"
      }
    }
*/
```

Comment: This is wrong because it will print same output even if there is no `start` word e.g. `four five two five six END seven`

Comment: thank you for explanaitions and time, but unfortunately, if you remove the start word, it does even capture the words.  Had to accept the other response.

Comment: @anubhava I'm not sure what you mean, remove the start word from where? It definitely will not capture the words after end; it would capture words from the start of the string if there was no `start` word

Comment: @anubhava okay, I suppose you're right... I had assumed that the data being searched would be relevant. However, it's a simple enough fix

Comment: @anubhava I have just done so and it works fine for me?? (assuming you set the flags correctly i.e. `i`)

Comment: Now please test your regex on `end two four five two five six END seven` (there is no `start` in this line)

Comment: @anubhava Not sure what you mean. That also tests good?

Comment: `end two four five two five six END` should not match any word because there is no `start` tag

Comment: @anubhava I'm fairly certain (as I tested it) that it wouldn't have matched any words for that line... However, your scenarios, have given me some ideas and I believe the new RegEx is about the simplest and most complete solution?

Comment: I don't want to make it never ending discussion but it will match words for input `END START two four five two five six seven` where it should not find anything.

Comment: @anubhava I've added it to the test strings and it **does not match** as you've suggested? (admittedly in the last edit I had copy/pasted the regex without the lookahead, without which it would match as you describe)

Comment: Test with `START foo END foo start one two END`